What is the shortest distance between elements of two finite sequences $a_n=n/N$ and $b_m=m/M$?
I stumbled upon this problem while programming. Let $M$ and $N$ be two positive integers and $n=1, ..., N-1$ and $m=1, ..., M-1$. What is the shortest distance between two elements $a_n$ and $b_m$, where $a_n = n/N$ and $b_m = m/M$?
Consider, for example, the sequences $\frac{1}{5}, \frac{2}{5}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5}$ and $\frac{1}{8}, \frac{2}{8}, \frac{3}{8}, ..., \frac{7}{8}$. The shortest distance is $0.025$, occurring between $\frac{3}{8}$ and $\frac{2}{5}$ and between $\frac{5}{8}$ and $\frac{3}{5}$. While both sequences simply divide the unit interval into equally spaced sections, it is not obvious how small the shortest distance is or where it occurs.
You can assume that $M$ and $N$ are coprime (it was not hard to figure out that the shortest distance is zero if there is a common divisor).
The shortest distance is easy to determine by brute force as long as $M$ and $N$ are reasonably small (sort the elements of both sequences in ascending order, subtract subsequent elements and look for the smallest result). For larger integers it would be desirable to calculate it directly, but I couldn't find a way to determine it mathematically. Since the problem involves prime numbers I wonder if it is actually a hard problem.

@RobArthan: I've taken the step of editing the expressions in from the title. OP, please check that this is what you intend, thanks!

@RobArthan: of course you're right. I must have missed that.

@BrianTung: Thanks, I think this is better now.

given your positive, coprime $M,N$   use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm for a solution to
$$  Mx - Ny = \pm 1  $$
You may adjust $x$  up or down by any multiple of $N$ as long as you adjust $y$  by the same multiple of $M.$   Anyway, force $1 \leq x \leq N-1. $  And $1 \leq y \leq M$   Finally
$$   \frac{x}{N}  - \frac{y}{M} = \pm  \frac{1}{MN}$$
First example
$$ 8 \cdot 2 - 5 \cdot 3 = 1$$
$$   \frac{2}{5}  - \frac{3}{8} =   \frac{1}{40}$$
Second example
$$ 12344 \cdot 1700 - 6789 \cdot 3091 = 1 $$
$$   \frac{1700}{6789}  - \frac{3091}{12344} =   \frac{1}{83803416}$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
This next one displays my extended Euclidean method. I never liked "back substitution."  Instead, I have the initial phase, the $n = q m + r$  give me the "coefficients"  of the (finite) continued fraction for the ratio. One message here: students have trouble juggling al the indices in the definition of continued fractions. However, it needs no indices   to carry out; and is not all that hard. First, practice the whole business below  with smaller numbers; say, find $\gcd(100, 61)$ as below, including the c.f.  and Bezout  formula $100 x - 61 y = \pm 1.$  In my example below, the penultimate "convergent" gives the Bezout coefficients. Note how each pair of consecutive convergents has a "crossed product" of $\pm 1$
$$  \gcd( 12345, 754 ) = ???    $$
$$ \frac{ 12345 }{ 754 } = 16 +  \frac{ 281 }{ 754 } $$
$$ \frac{ 754 }{ 281 } = 2 +  \frac{ 192 }{ 281 } $$
$$ \frac{ 281 }{ 192 } = 1 +  \frac{ 89 }{ 192 } $$
$$ \frac{ 192 }{ 89 } = 2 +  \frac{ 14 }{ 89 } $$
$$ \frac{ 89 }{ 14 } = 6 +  \frac{ 5 }{ 14 } $$
$$ \frac{ 14 }{ 5 } = 2 +  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 } $$
$$ \frac{ 5 }{ 4 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 4 } $$
$$ \frac{ 4 }{ 1 } = 4 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$
Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 16 & & 2 & & 1 & & 2 & & 6 & & 2 & & 1 & & 4 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 16 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 33 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 49 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 131 }{ 8 }   & &   \frac{ 835 }{ 51 }   & &   \frac{ 1801 }{ 110 }   & &   \frac{ 2636 }{ 161 }   & &   \frac{ 12345 }{ 754 }  
 \end{array}
 $$
$$  $$
$$ 12345 \cdot 161 - 754 \cdot 2636 = 1 $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
